# Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am currently using the approach from https://github.com/madskristensen/vswebessentials.com/blob/master/Website/Views/_Layout.cshtml in an "old" Razor app. In porting to Core 2.1, I haven't found an equivalent for `Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath` (I intend to publish with `MvcRazorCompileOnPublish` set to `false`, so the cshtml file would be there for cache invalidation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IPageFilter` `OnPageHandlerSelected` method to access the `ActionDescriptor` for the current page. It exposes a RelativePath property which gives you the relative file path for the current page:

```
public override void OnPageHandlerSelected(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
{
    var file = context.ActionDescriptor.RelativePath;
}
```

You can read more about the `IPageFilter` and its methods here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/filters